# How to solve xliff not a valid format string error

Tags: java, android, string

I've been scratching ahead over an error being shown by Android studio in the code inspector.  It compiles and runs fine, but the following Java line (in MainActivity.java) :

```
builder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.rest_line, i) + "\n");
```

Is underlined in red, with the following message:

> Format string "rest_line" is not a valid format string to it should not be passed to String.format

Here's the relevant parts of my Strings.xml:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="rest_line">Rest <xliff:g example="3" id="period_no">%d</xliff:g> : </string>
</resources>
```

Output should be, for example:

Rest 2 :

Any ideas?  It looks correct to me, but I've obviously done something odd.

Charlie

Comment: `%1$d` instead of `%d` maybe. But rather I think `<xliff` should be `&lt;xliff` whatever the consequences. No experience

Comment: That doesn't work, I'm afraid.  The <xliff... part is an XML tag, so I don't need to treat the "<" as a special character.  The %1 addition makes no difference.